# How do you remove a object from a list in C++?

Tags: c++

This is where I'm having the problem. I need to remove a object from the array once the creature dies.

```
for each(BaseObject monster in MonsterList)
                        {
                            if(MonsterSelect == monster.GetName())
                            {
                                Damage = Player.GetATK() - monster.GetDEF();
                                monster.SetHP(monster.GetHP() - Damage);
                                cout << monster.GetName() << " has taken " << Damage << "." << endl;
                                if(monster.GetAliveFlag() == false)
                                {
                                    cout << monster.GetName() << " has died." << endl;
                                MonsterList.remove(monster);//This is where the object needs to be removed.
                                    int sdf = 234;
                                }

                            }
                        }
```

Comment: `for each(BaseObject monster in MonsterList)` uhh... what? This wouldnt even compile. Whats your problem exactly?

Comment: You use list and array in the same question, please clarify what you're using.

Comment: C++ ??? You sure this is C++ ? Give us more details. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That 'for each' is a microsoft one

Comment: It's a list and I'm using C++.

Comment: @THOMAS 'It's a list and I'm using C++' should be: It's a MFC list using MFC C++ extensions

Comment: @DieterLücking: I don't think "MFC" is what you really meant there. MFC is a strictly a class library--it doesn't affect the basic syntax of the language. Looks to me more likely some sort of C++/CLI or C++/CX thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ordinary for loop with iterators and apply method erase for the list.

Something like this

```
for ( auto it = MonsterList.begin(); it != MonsterList.end(); )
{
    //...
    if( MonsterSelect == it->GetName())
    {
        //,,,    
        if( it->GetAliveFlag() == false)
        {
            it = MonsterList.erase( it );
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

You can reformat the loop that it would be more readable.

I suppose that each time when the current monster satisfies some condition you have to remove only this one monster in the list.

As for method remove then it removes all elements of the list that are equal to the given monster.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to interpret this as asking how you'd accomplish this basic task in decently written C++.

First, I'd get rid of the `for` loop. Second, I'd move most of the logic into one class or the other. Right now, these look like quasi-classes to me--i.e., all the real logic is in separate code operating on a couple of what are basically dumb data objects, disguised as classes by using accessors to get at the raw data.

So, if you were doing this in actual C++, you might end up with a map (or multimap) to let you find monsters by name. So, you'd have something like this:

```
auto monster = monsters.find(monsterSelect);
if (monster == monsters.end())
    // Not found

if (monster.kill(player.attack())) {
    cout << monsterSelect << " has died.\n";
    monsters.erase(monster);
}
```

For the moment, I'm assuming there's really only a single monster by any one name. If this might really be an attack against multiple monsters, you have a couple of choices.

The preferred one (at least IMO) is to decouple the "battle the monster" part from the "remove dead monster(s) from the list" part. I'd probably use a Boost filter-iterator to iterate across all the monsters by a given name, then the remove/erase idiom to remove all the dead monsters from the list. (Note, however, that the remove/erase idiom is specific to sequential collections, and not suitable for associative containers).